# How HibernateValidator finds ConstraintValidator when validatedBy is empty?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I wonder how Hibernate finds `NullValidator` class which extends `ConstraintValidator` interface even if `@Null` annotation definition as follows:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface Null {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`validatedBy` only needs to be specified for custom (i.e. user-created) constraints. All the built-in constraints that are known to Hibernate are mapped automatically. See the following code, which appears in `ConstraintDescriptorImpl` and `XmlMappingParser`:

```
if ( constraintHelper.isBuiltinConstraint( annotationType ) ) {
    constraintDefinitionClasses.addAll( constraintHelper.getBuiltInConstraints( annotationType ) );
}
else {
    Class<? extends ConstraintValidator<?, ?>>[] validatedBy = annotationType
            .getAnnotation( Constraint.class )
            .validatedBy();
    constraintDefinitionClasses.addAll( Arrays.asList( validatedBy ) );
}
```

`ConstraintHelper` has a list of all the built-in constraints, which will be found by the `isBuiltinConstraint` method for these annotation types.